# How to get original referrer url when invoking javascript??

Tags: javascript, referrer

Let us take i am in site named `domain1.com` and navigating to another site `domain2.com`, where i invoke a external js call.

The problem is the referrer of the js call is `domain2.com` and but i need the original referrer i.e. `domain1.com`. I see that the google analytics request, i see that the query parameter utmr hold the referrer url. example - [utmr](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/&rct=j&q=stack%20overflow&ei=h0XETcL2IJOisQOCjeWXAQ&usg=AFQjCNERidL9Hb6OvGW93_Y6MRj3aTdMVA&sig2=FSy1Krjsn8B9Njr0Pz3YxA)

Any idea how to get the same as that in GA ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution, it is simple. The document.referrer added in external script works fine and provide the referrer URL of the current page.

Thank you
Balaji

Answer (score 0):

Some questions:

1. Do you have control over `domain2.com`?
2. Do you have control over the external js that you are calling?
3. If not, is there a way to pass a different referer via a parameter?

**You cannot change the referer page on a service call you are making to another service.**  However, the source code on `domain2.com` containing the external js call will have access to its own referer on `domain1.com`, and will need to pass it as a parameter, providing the remote JS interface allows passing a referer parameter.  This is accessible through the server code language you are using.  For example, here it is in `PHP`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var referer = "<?php echo $HTTP_REFERER; ?>";
    doRemoteCall("theRemotePage?referer=" + referer);
</script>
```

Comment: hi - i dont have control over domain2.com but i have control over external.js.

Comment: @Balaji: Then there really is no way to get that first referrer, unless, domain2.com passes it on to you directly.

Comment: @Meallamokb - i see that the google analytics is able to fetch the original referrer. you can in the GA call where utmr query parameter contains the original referrer.